# haskell read from file

Tags: string, haskell, line

i'm trying to read from file in haskell and process every line
what i have now

```
main = interact (unlines . (map calculate) . lines)
```

this let me get every line from input and send it to calculate

now i want to get every line from a file and send it to calculate

this is what i tried

```
main = do 
    text <- readFile "input.txt"
    let linii = lines text
    interact (unlines . (map calculate) . linii)
```

tell me please how is it correct?

UPDATE below

```
calculate :: String -> String
calculate s=
    case ret of
        Left e -> "error: " ++(show e)
        Right n -> "answer: " ++ (show n)
    where
        ret = parse parseInput "" s

main :: IO()
--main = interact (unlines . (map calculate) . lines)
main = do text <- readFile "input.txt"
          let linii = lines
          putStrLn . unlines $ map calculate linii
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Write it to another file? Just output to console?

Comment: @kirelagin I assumed printing to the console. At the very least, it is a resonable next step to make sure everything works so far before writing to a file.

Comment: Does your update solve the problem? If not, what happens when you run it?

Answer (score 7):

Remember that `interact` takes input from stdin and sends output to stdout. Since you have already read input from a file, you don't need the former. You only need to do the later. You can print a String with `putStrln`. Putting this all together, change

```
interact (unlines . (map calculate) . linii)
```

to

```
putStrLn . unlines $ map calculate linii
```

Comment: Haskell is particular about indentation. Be sure that all the lines after `main = do` are indented and lined up to start at exactly the same column. In your code here, you have an extra space before `let`.

Comment: i indented it correctly and now Couldn't match expected type `[String]'
                with actual type `String -> [String]'
my function calculate :: String -> String

Comment: @StefanFlondor double-check your file, the code in this answer is fine.

Comment: @StefanFlondor, This final line is equivalent to `putStrLn ((unlines . map calculate . lines) text)`.  Note well its similarities to the `interact` line.